# Ember 1.0 Final Internet Explorer 8 and 9 (History API - pushState and replaceState)

Tags: ember.js

I was under the impression that Ember was well tested under some older versions of IE. However, upon finally firing up my near complete app (form wizard). I'm noticing IE is complaining about replaceState and pushState, two methods that are not supported according to http://caniuse.com/#search=pushState

Are there any workarounds for this?

`SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'replaceState'`

`get(this, 'history').replaceState(state, null, path);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

UPDATE: As of Ember 1.5.0+ I can confirm that they added 'auto' which should eliminate the need for the example below.

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'auto'
});
```

---

Original Answer:

Apparently you need to feature detect the history API:

```
if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
  App.Router.reopen({
    location: 'history'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no work around.  If you need to use real URLs (/users) instead of hash URLs (/#/users) then you have to either exclude IE 8 & 9 from your list of supported browsers, or you need to use Ember in a "progressive enhancement" manner, still serve valid content from the server for each real URL that is visited, and use feature detection to selectively enable your Ember app.

Answer (score 0):

To properly support both pushSate and non-pushState browsers, you need to have a translator between the 2 different state mechanisms.

For example, let's say your rootURL is '/admin/' and you start with this URL:

/admin/users/123

For IE8/9, you'll want to redirect the user to '/admin/#/users/123' before Ember's routing mechanism takes over.  Likewise, if you start with this URL:

/admin/#/users/123

...then for browsers that support pushState, you'll want to replace the state to '/admin/users/123' before Ember's routing mechanism takes over.

This is the default behavior of Backbone's router and it works fairly well.
To achieve this result in Ember, you can do something like this, which was inspired by Backbone's source code:

```
App.Router.reopen({
    rootURL: '/admin/',

    init: function () {
        this.translateRoute();
        this._super();
    },

    translateRoute: function () {

        var hasPushState = window.history && window.history.pushState;
        var atRoot = window.location.pathname === this.rootURL;
        var fragment = decodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname);
        if (!fragment.indexOf(this.rootURL))
            fragment = fragment.substr(this.rootURL.length);

        if (hasPushState)
            this.location = 'history';

        // If we started with a route from a pushState-enabled browser, 
        // but we're currently in a browser that doesn't support it...
        if (!hasPushState && !atRoot) {
            window.location.replace(this.rootURL + '#/' + fragment);
            return;
        }

        // If we started with a hash-based route,
        // but we're currently in a browser that supports pushState...
        if (hasPushState && atRoot && window.location.hash) {
            fragment = window.location.hash.replace(/^(#\/|[#\/])/, '');
            window.history.replaceState({}, document.title, window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + this.rootURL + fragment);
        }
    }
});
```